# Keep javascript running in browser console, even after new pageload

Tags: javascript

Say I have a script that I ran in the console:

```
var counter = 0;
var i = setInterval(function() {
    // perform a number of actions here
    counter++;
    if (counter == 20) {
        clearInterval(i);
        $('a#next_page')[0].click();
        counter = 0;
    }
}, 1000);
```

When it gets to the action of clicking on the `#next_page` anchor, it loads a new page, thus removing the script I pasted into the console. Is there a way to keep the script running inside the console despite what pages you navigate to?

Comment: No. Not without something that lives outside of the sandbox, like a browser extension or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this scenario: A script is executed in the contemporary browser's JavaScript console. This console has no such requested functionality (auto-injection) of said JavaScript code when a new page is loaded.
If there is no auxiliary script in the new page loaded, it won't work. Possible workarounds:

1. Loading the new content [through XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) instead and manipulating [the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries)
2. Implementation as [browser extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), finding a browser extension that already supports that or [shipping the whole browser with your product](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-bridge.html#thin-clients)
3. Have a full-sized `<iframe>` whose `src` attribute is manipulated instead

If the issue was that the text entered in the edit box of the JS console disappeared, there might be some settings to prevent that but this requires knowing which browser and which JavaScript console is being used by the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iFrame. The iFrame occupies full width and height of the site. On the site where you include the iFrame you can place your JavaScript code. Of course this only works within the same website. Otherwise you should use a browser extension.