# Making script keep working after navigated to different page

Tags: javascript, redirect, navigation

I'm very new to scripts! Sorry, my question would be somewhat low level one.

I guess I'm using javascripts!

Suppose that the page I'm working on is A. I don't know how I make my code work work, but I have a script that works very well on page A. It is basically repeating the same function infinitely.

However, if I stay more than one hour, the server redirect me to another page (Named as B).

I want to come back to page A and make function work again after the server redirect(navigate) me to page B.

So, I searched web and I thought the 'setTimeout' function would do.

So my codes are like below;

```
function functionA_that_repeats_infinetly_on_pageA{
    functionA's content ~~
    ~~
    if( stopBeforeRedirect()) {
        setTimeout(Redirect, 1000*70);
    }
}
```

*stopBeforeRedirect() is a function that returns True when the time I spent on page A is longer than 59 minutes 
*Redirect() is a function that redirects me to Page A

I thought that after I spent more than 59 minutes on Page A, stopBeforeRedirect function would return True, hence trigger the setTimeout function and after one minute from then, the server would redirect me to Page B, then after 10 seconds(because the setTimeout function waits for 70 seconds and trigger Redirect()) the Redirect() function would bring me to Page A.

However, I found that it doesn't work and just stuck to Page B.

I think this is because, after the server redirect me to page B, my script stops working.

I'm doing this by copying the code above into Chrome console.

Can anyone help me dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**script you created for a specific page works only inside this page**

but i think you can use **`onbeforeunload`** event to stop redirecting **or** at least do stop your **js** function safely before redirecting :

here a simple **code** :

```js
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
         //here you can do what you need before leaving the page
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        };
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">redirect to w3</a>
```

and take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867066/keep-javascript-running-in-browser-console-even-after-new-pageload) he use a iframe Trick

I hope that can help